# RN8213 software pack for Keil µVision 5

Tags: microcontroller, arm, cortex-m

I am having a problem developing a firmware for RN8213 Cortex-M0 microcontroller from Renergy company. I installed the Keil µVision 5 development tool but I can't find the software package for RN8213 in the software pack installer. How can I solve this problem?

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Renergy is not listed as a manufacturer which Keil supports on their [device page](https://www.keil.arm.com/devices/). You could probably treat it as a 'Generic Cortex M0' device, but without support in the tool for your specific device you'll be on your own for defining all the peripheral registers, etc. I'd expect that Renergy could help with that though.

Answer (score 1):

I solve the problem by adding legacy device database in Keil µVision 5 thank you for your support
[image]

Comment: Thanks for closing the loop. It would be an even better answer if you mentioned where you downloaded the database and how it is installed (or a link to the latter).